# Can @JoinColumn refer to a previously defined field, or otherwise, what is happening here?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I got a code with an Id column and a OneToOne join in my class Thing.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private ThingExtension thingExtension;
```

Is this working like the following?

```
   Thing                     ThingExtension 
-------------------          --------------
  id (PK,FK) ------------->  id
-----------------            --------------
```

or is it creating twice the id field or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case JPA provider create only one column `id`.

Another way to do this:

You can use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation. Remove `@JoinColumn` and add `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` (without parameters).

From JPA reference:

> The PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation specifies that
>   a primary key column is to be used as a for-eign key.